# My HTML form doesn't search the MDM. How can I find what the site uses to process search queries?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form on a private web page that *should* bring up search results for MDN in a new tab - but doesn't. After scouring the web I've found nothing to explain why.

```
<form action='https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?' target='_blank' method="get">
<input name='query'>
<input type="hidden" name="topic" value="html" />
<input type="hidden" name="skill" value="advanced" />
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="code" />
<button>Search</button>
</form>
```

The form sends the correct GET request [like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?query=acronym&topic=html&skill=advanced&type=code) 
and the URL of the loaded page matches.

However the results are as if I just loaded the search page with topic selected as html, skill as advanced, and type as code **without** entering a search term. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?query=acronym&topic=html&skill=advanced&type=code

What I want is the same results as if I was to type acronym into the page loaded by the previous URL, which is **Results 162 documents found for "acronym" in English (US). Showing results 1 to 10**. Instead of **Results 417 documents found in English (US). Showing results 1 to 10**.

As far as I can tell the headers from the form are identical to those when I manually load the search page. My guess is that I haven't allowed for javascript.

**Solved:** thanks Teison T. and Jon P

Comment: `query` should be just `q`, from what I can tell: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=acronym&topic=html&skill=advanced&type=code

Comment: Thanks, that works. Special thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `query` in your query string and replace with `q`. Your final URL should look like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=acronym&topic=html&skill=advanced&type=code

Comment: Usually I just type a query on a web site and examine the headers to build an appropriate form. Without access to a sites developer information how would you suggest I avoid the previous error (the header showed "query" not "q"?

Comment: With get requests it's easier to check the URL

Comment: That was a GET request, and using the URL was easier - but I still didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

As Teison T. and Jon P suggested, changing "query" to just "q" solves the problem.

Comment: Instead of adding an answer, you can indicate the accepted answer by clicking the check mark and/or clicking the up arrow next to the answer to up  vote it.

Comment: Um, I did that. The adding of the answer was because of one of the many suck features of this site - so the first, and most detailed answer got some credit. Noted that my question got modded down for mystical reasons.